# Pass variables from Android Activity to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

Say I have two variables, x and y and I want to pass them from MyActivity to JavaScript. Here's my code:

```
public class myNewActivity extends Activity {
    double x;
    double y;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        // get extras passed from another activity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            x = extras.getDouble("x");
            y = extras.getDouble("y");
        }

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        //webView.loadUrl("javascript:setX('"+x+"')");
        //webView.loadUrl("javascript:setY('"+y+"')");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");    
    }
```

I was trying something with the two commented lines but was just crashing the app. This is the JavaScript:

```
var x, y;
    function init(){
        // ... here I need the values of X and Y

    }
    function setX(ex) {
        x = ex;
    }
    function setY(ey) {
        y = ey
    }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: You would run the `loadUrl` for your js *after* the page has loaded (in `onPageCompleted()`). Instead of implementing `setX` and `setY`, just provide a `setXY` -- one less call.

Comment: @323go But don't I need the values before if I want to display them on the page I'm loading? Is there some other way?

Comment: "But don't I need the values before if I want to display them on the page I'm loading?" I don't know, do you? It depends on how your html looks. If yes, then you might need to load the index.html first, modify it in memory and load it with `loadData()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement javascriptinteface in webview like this;

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    double x = 0, y = 0;
    if (extras != null) {
        x = extras.getDouble("x");
        y = extras.getDouble("y");
    }
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(x, y), "JSInterface");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

**Create This Javainteface in your activity**

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

        double x, y;

        JavaScriptInterface(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double getXValue() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getYValue() {
            return y;

        }
    }
```

**In you index.html**

```
var x, y;
    function init(){
       x = JSInterface.getXValue();
       y = JSInterface.getYValue();
    }
```

Comment: the Bundle extra is always null !! what to do ?

Comment: @Suda.nese Answer given is in respect to asked question. It is example how to communicate with javascript. You need to pass from previous activity in bundle extras to read here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I wasn't passing any extras and the bundle was null. Now you answer works for me. Thanks again for your solution.